# Adobe AEM DAM asset email should add the correct hostname, not localhost

Tags: email, localhost, assets, aem, dam

I am facing a little issue with the DAM asset email. Email is working fine, but it is always sending a url with the localhost, which is incorrect. The client should get email with the actual host name rather than the localhost. Please let me know if we need to do any configuration to show the actual host name.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration "Day CQ Workflow Email Notification Service" to set server name. Please go to OSGI Config console, search for "Day CQ Workflow Email Notification Service" service and set "Host URL Prefix" property.

Comment: Hi Mohit, Thanks for the response that is already configured but it doesn't pick up this host name when we download the asset through email.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across the same problem. The solution is  :

As given in Adobe AEM Forum [here](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__9uyj-experts_i_spend.html)

You need to map your localhost to a domain in your web server

Also check this to setup dispatcher

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html

and https setup

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-ssl.html

**OR**

Configure the `externalizer.host` property of "Day CQ Externalizer" OSGI configuration using AEM OSGI console i.e. http://localhost:4052/system/console/configMgr